# Javascript naming convention for related DOM elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, naming-conventions

I ask because I'm writing an Angular directive requiring me to reference the parent and grandparent element. This means I end up with long names for something like the 'grand parents' innerheight. Something like:

```
var grandParentInnerHeight = $grandParent.innerHeight();
```

A friend suggested using nth to name these, but using numbers also seems wrong when it comes to naming variables.

And I know some people might suggest to restructure my code so I don't need the grand parent, but in this case its necessary.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen people use abbreviations like

`var gpInnerHeight = foo;`

or

`var grandPInnerHeight = foo;`

But personally, I find no problem in writing the full name of a variable. It makes it clear to understand, but just takes a couple more ms to write it.

Also, for JQuery, I've seen some people who want to distinguish between JavaScript variables and JQuery variables by putting a `$` in front of them like this.

`var $grandParentInnerHeight = foo.innerHeight();`

Here's a website that goes over some naming conventions that I see as useful.

[Click me](http://www.j-io.org/Javascript-Naming_Conventions)

Comment: I avoid abbreviating because it can always be misinterpreted. I guess this works, but I still dislike the long name. Thanks.